# Excel - ClosedXML - Best way to get visible rows following applying SetAutoFilter/AddFilter?

Tags: c#, excel, autofilter, closedxml

Using this example, https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML_Examples/AutoFilters/RegularAutoFilter.cs

ws.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter.Column(1).AddFilter("123");
ws.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter.Column(2).AddFilter("abc");

I'm successfully filtering a table by multiple columns.  Let's say it has 20 rows, and applying the filter reduces the ***visible*** rows to 2 (rows 7 & 12).

Great, the filter works, but how can I *quickly* get the *visible* rows?

Right now, I'm having to loop through the entire range used to find the rows that are visible, hence match the filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
var visibleRows = ws.RangeUsed().Rows(r => !r.WorksheetRow().IsHidden);
```

Comment: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/877 adds a helper property to simplify this.